How to repair corrupt .docx file
I tried many repair programs without success. Here is the file on Google Docs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rUaVK0G6rBlgAf-Cu8fSkuhhDd406K8q/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118096348047738996435&rtpof=true&sd=true

Can you edit the question to include (a) what error is reported on trying to open the file (b) what repair software has been tried.
